# pandas dataframe memory python

Tags: python, pandas, memory, dataframe, scikit-learn

i want to transform a sparse matrix (156060x11780) to dataframe but i get a memory error this is my code

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, analyzer='word', 
                       stop_words='english' , tokenizer=tokenize,
                       strip_accents = 'ascii') 

X = vect.fit_transform(df.pop('Phrase')).toarray()

for i, col in enumerate(vect.get_feature_names()):
    df[col] = X[:, i]
```

I have a problem in  `X = vect.fit_transform(df.pop('Phrase')).toarray()`. How can i solve it?

Comment: does this work for you `X = vect.fit_transform(df.pop('Phrase')).todense()`?

Comment: no :( i tried it before

Comment: How much RAM is available ?

Comment: 12 Go i use linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, analyzer='word', stop_words='english',
                       tokenizer=tokenize,
                       strip_accents='ascii',dtype=np.float16)
X = vect.fit_transform(df.pop('Phrase'))  # NOTE: `.toarray()` was removed


for i, col in enumerate(vect.get_feature_names()):
    df[col] = pd.SparseSeries(X[:, i].toarray().reshape(-1,), fill_value=0)
```

**UPDATE:** for Pandas 0.20+ we can construct `SparseDataFrame` directly from sparse arrays:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, analyzer='word', stop_words='english',
                       tokenizer=tokenize,
                       strip_accents='ascii',dtype=np.float16)

df = pd.SparseDataFrame(vect.fit_transform(df.pop('Phrase')),
                        columns=vect.get_feature_names(),
                        index=df.index)
```

---

**UPDATE from 2022-01-22** in modern versions of Pandas the `pd.SparseDataFrame` method has been deprecated, so please use [pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html) instead.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you

Comment: In the new version of Pandas, `SparseDataFrame()` is no longer available. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040020/5936342

Comment: @revy, thank you for pointing this out! I've updated my answer)