# How load a data set contains txt file in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, svm

I am going to use scikit-learn libraries for my SVM implementation for classification.

My features' values are 0/1 and I have saved these values in a txt file for features and a separate txt file for my labels.

Now my problem is that how I can load my external data set for training and test phase using scikit-learn?

Comment: Check out the docs of numpy or pandas. Both got functions for reading csv-files. If your files are not really csv-like, you have to parse them yourself. You won't get much more help as all the details are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving vectorized and especially compressed (sparse) data in a TXT/CSV file is not the best approach as you might have problems when reading it back - you will lose dtypes, compression/"sparseness", etc.. You may even encounter cases when you will not be able to read your TXT/CSV file in memory.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916560/pandas-dataframe-memory-python) you can see an example when converting sparse matrix to a normal (numpy) one ends with `MemoryError`. It may happen to you if you will save your sparse (compressed) matrix to CSV and then will try to read it back (uncompressed).

So i would recommend you to use [pickling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html):

saving / serializing your data:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')
```

where `clf` is your trained model or another sparse/compressed data structure

reading it back from disk:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your illustration. I am going to try your instructions.

Comment: @Shahrooz, did it help?

Comment: yes and thanks for your help. I just do not know how can I set gama and c parameters in my classifier. Do I must set these parameters manually for every run or they will be set automatically? If they will be set automatically, how can I find their values?