# Logical not on a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a bag-of-words representation of a corpus stored in an *D* by *W* sparse matrix `word_freqs`. Each row is a document and each column is a word. A given element `word_freqs[d,w]` represents the number of occurrences of word *w* in document *d*.

I'm trying to obtain another *D* by *W* matrix `not_word_occs` where, for each element of `word_freqs`:

- If `word_freqs[d,w]` is zero, `not_word_occs[d,w]` should be one.
- Otherwise, `not_word_occs[d,w]` should be zero.

Eventually, this matrix will need to be multiplied with other matrices which might be dense or sparse.

---

I've tried a number of methods, including:

```
not_word_occs = (word_freqs == 0).astype(int)
```

This words for toy examples, but results in a `MemoryError` for my actual data (which is approx. 18,000x16,000).

I've also tried `np.logical_not()`:

```
word_occs = sklearn.preprocessing.binarize(word_freqs)
not_word_occs = np.logical_not(word_freqs).astype(int)
```

This seemed promising, but `np.logical_not()` does not work on sparse matrices, giving the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

---

Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.

(By the way, `word_freqs` is generated by sklearn's `preprocessing.CountVectorizer()`. If there's a solution that involves converting this to another kind of matrix, I'm certainly open to that.)

Comment: If `word_freqs` is a scipy sparse matrix, it should have print representation that shows shape, number of nonzero values, dtype and sparse format.

Comment: `<18144x14511 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
        with 619900 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

Comment: So it is .002 sparse.  The `not` then will all 99.8% ones.

Comment: @err1100, would you consider using Pandas.SparseDataFrame instead of scipy sparse matrixes?

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed, but see my comment below. I eventually need to multiply it with other matrices. Can I do that with pandas?

Comment: @err1100, how much RAM is available for Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of the nonzero positions of a sparse matrix is dense. So if you want to achieve your stated goals with standard numpy arrays you will require quite a bit of RAM. Here's a quick and totally unscientific hack to give you an idea, how many arrays of that sort your computer can handle:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = []
>>> for j in range(100):
...     print(j)
...     a.append(np.ones((16000, 18000), dtype=int))
```

My laptop chokes at j=1. So unless you have a really good computer even if you can get the complement (you can do

```
>>> compl = np.ones(S.shape,int)
>>> compl[S.nonzero()] = 0
```

) memory will be an issue.

One way out may be to not explicitly compute the complement let's call it C = B1 - A, where B1 is the same-shape matrix completely filled with ones and A the adjacency matrix of your original sparse matrix. For example the matrix product XC can be written as XB1 - XA so you have one multiplication with the sparse A and one with B1 which is actually cheap because it boils down to computing row sums. The point here is that you can compute that without computing C first.

A particularly simple example would be multiplication with a one-hot vector. Such a multiplication just selects a column (if multiplying from the right) or row (if multiplying from the left) of the other matrix. Meaning you just need to find that column or row of the sparse matrix and take the complement (for a single slice no problem) and if you do this for a one-hot matrix, as above you needn't compute the complement explicitly.

Comment: I think I follow you, but what is "the adjacency matrix of [my] original sparse matrix"?

Comment: @err1100 Oh, jargon, sorry. It's the same matrix with all nonzero entries set to one. Btw. I'm pretty sure the scheme I describe in the last paragraph will be applicable to one-hot matrices. Let me think a bit and I'll add a few lines.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I was able to get things working thanks to your decomposition. Computing the actual matrices still used too much RAM (specifically, making a 16K by 18K matrix of ones), but your one-hot paragraph allowed me to figure out how to do that without making the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Make a small sparse matrix:

```
In [743]: freq = sparse.random(10,10,.1)
In [744]: freq
Out[744]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

the `repr(freq)` shows the shape, elements and format.

```
In [745]: freq==0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:213: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing a sparse matrix with 0 using == is inefficient, try using != instead.
  ", try using != instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[745]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 90 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

If do your first action, I get a warning and new array with 90 (out of 100) nonzero terms.  That `not` is no longer sparse.

In general numpy functions do not work when applied to sparse matrices.  To work they have to delegate the task to sparse methods. But even if `logical_not` worked it wouldn't solve the memory issue.

Comment: In that case, do you have any suggestions? For context, I have a one-hot _D_ by _K_ matrix `doc_topics` representing the topic of each document. Later on, I need to end up with a _W_ by _K_ matrix that tells me how many documents of topic _k_ do _not_ contain word _w_. With my toy examples, I was accomplishing this with `not_word_occs.T @ doc_topics`, but I now need another way to do that.

Comment: @hpaulj Once I try to use the logical not this way, if I try to do a Hadamard product with another sparse matrix, I get a dimension mismatch error, which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using [Pandas.SparseDataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html):

```
In [42]: X = (sparse.rand(10, 10, .1) != 0).astype(np.int64)

In [43]: X = (sparse.rand(10, 10, .1) != 0).astype(np.int64)

In [44]: d1 = pd.SparseDataFrame(X.toarray(), default_fill_value=0, dtype=np.int64)

In [45]: d2 = pd.SparseDataFrame(np.ones((10,10)), default_fill_value=1, dtype=np.int64)

In [46]: d1.memory_usage()
Out[46]:
Index    80
0        16
1         0
2         8
3        16
4         0
5         0
6        16
7        16
8         8
9         0
dtype: int64

In [47]: d2.memory_usage()
Out[47]:
Index    80
0         0
1         0
2         0
3         0
4         0
5         0
6         0
7         0
8         0
9         0
dtype: int64
```

math:

```
In [48]: d2 - d1
Out[48]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
5  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
6  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
7  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1
8  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
9  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

source sparse matrix:

```
In [49]: d1
Out[49]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

memory usage:

```
In [50]: (d2 - d1).memory_usage()
Out[50]:
Index    80
0        16
1         0
2         8
3        16
4         0
5         0
6        16
7        16
8         8
9         0
dtype: int64
```

PS if you can't build the whole SparseDataFrame at once (because of memory constraints), you can use an [approach similar to one used in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41916672/5741205)