# I am currently getting this error when running my code: TypeError: SparseDataFrame() takes no arguments. How do I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I am currently getting this error when running my code: TypeError: SparseDataFrame() takes no arguments. How do I fix this?

View the code below.

```
churndrop = churn.drop(['Churn'],axis=1) #drops churn column

x= churndrop #creates dataframe 

y= churntarget # creates dataframe
y = np.ravel(y) # unravels y
y # shows y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #imports sklearn
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0) # creates 
#test and train data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler #import scaller

sc = StandardScaler() # sets sc to standard scaler
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train) #transforms data
X_test = sc.transform(X_test) # transforms data

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2) # test train
#x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.4)# extra line 
import light_famd # imports famd
from light_famd import FAMD #famd

famd= FAMD(n_components=2) # creates famd variable with two components


famd.fit_transform(x_test) # fits test

print(famd.explained_variance_) # prints variance

print(famd.explained_variance_rati`enter code here`o_) # prints explained variance
```

Answer (score 4):

In the new version of Pandas, `SparseDataFrame()` is no longer available which is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html).

> Note
>
> SparseSeries and SparseDataFrame were removed in pandas 1.0.0. This
>   migration guide is present to aid in migrating from previous versions

So, for example, from the Docs,

```
#Previous Method
pd.SparseDataFrame({"A": [0, 1]})

#New Method
pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.arrays.SparseArray([0, 1])})
```

For More, Visit the [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html)